# dict.get() method returns a pointer

Tags: python, dictionary, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have this code:

```
my_dict = {}
default_value = {'surname': '', 'age': 0}

# get info about john, or a default dict
item = my_dict.get('john', default_value)

# edit the data
item[surname] = 'smith'
item[age] = 68

my_dict['john'] = item
```

The problem becomes clear, if we now check the value of default_value:

```
>>> default_value
{'age': 68, 'surname': 'smith'}
```

It is obvious, that `my_dict.get()` did not return the **value** of default_value, but a pointer (?) to it.

The problem could be worked around by changing the code to:

```
item = my_dict.get('john', {'surname': '', 'age': 0})
```

but that doesn't seem to be a nice way to do it. Any ideas, comments?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
item = my_dict.get('john', default_value.copy())
```

You're *always* passing a reference in Python.

This doesn't matter for immutable objects like `str`, `int`, `tuple`, etc. since you can't change them, only point a name at a different object, but it does for mutable objects like `list`, `set`, and `dict`. You need to get used to this and always keep it in mind.

**Edit:** Zach Bloom and Jonathan Sternberg both point out methods you can use to avoid the call to `copy` on every lookup. You should use either the `defaultdict` method, something like Jonathan's first method, or:

```
def my_dict_get(key):
    try:
        item = my_dict[key]
    except KeyError:
        item = default_value.copy()
```

This will be faster than `if` when the key nearly always already exists in `my_dict`, **if the `dict` is large**. You don't have to wrap it in a function but you probably don't want those four lines every time you access `my_dict`.

See Jonathan's answer for timings with a small `dict`. The `get` method performs poorly at all sizes I tested, but the `try` method does better at large sizes.

Comment: This is a very important tenet of python - *all* values are passed by reference.  The mutability of those references is an entirely different issue (although it often trips people up in this way).

Comment: I'm sure I have read about it before, but you tend to forget things when not using a language for a long time. Thanks for making that clear.

Comment: Why is your answer any different to the answer provided in the question. Question seems to be more about finding an elegant way of returning a new instance of the  dict, but only creating it as and when needed.

Comment: The question was about not typing `{'surname': '', 'age': 0}` every time he needed to do a `get`, and by extension about how arguments are passed in Python, not about not creating it every time. I've pointed to the other answers that mention that issue, however, and added an alternative.

Comment: @agf see my answer for speed timings. The use of try/except will slow that answer down far more than he probably wants.

Comment: I did some more timings, and the `get` method wasn't faster for any `dict` size -- surprising to me. The `try` method, however, _is_ faster than the double lookup for large `dict`s -- something like 10% for 10,000-1,000,000 entries. If you have a high ratio of hits to misses, that could make it worthwhile to use `try`.

Comment: -1: All values are assigned and *passed by value* in Python. All values in Python are references (same with non-primitives in Java). "Pass by reference" has a very specific meaning meaning that is is possible to re-assign the variable in the calling scope, which is not the case in Python. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006

Comment: Yes, I was simplifying. I'll edit to say "you're always passing _a reference_" instead of "by reference" so as not to confuse people who might take it literally.

Comment: @agf: Note that when calling `my_dict.get('john', default_value.copy())`, even if 'john' is in my_dict, `default_value.copy()` always gets executed: a copy of default_value is created even if it is not returned. This explains part of the performance issue when using the get method.

Comment: @Remi Yes, I know. Did you read the rest of the post? Or the other answers? That's what the whole thread is about. Even if you use `dict.get()` in other constructions, it still has overhead that using keywords doesn't.

Comment: @agf: you are right, I see it now, you and others mentioned it indeed; Sorry, think it's time for me to shut up and go to sleep...

Comment: @Remi Hah, sorry for the tone of that last, I was in fact about to go to sleep myself when I posted it :)

Answer (score 12):

Don't use get. You could do:

```
item = my_dict.get('john', default_value.copy())
```

But this requires a dictionary to be copied *even if the dictionary entry exists*. Instead, consider just checking if the value is there.

```
item = my_dict['john'] if 'john' in my_dict else default_value.copy()
```

The only problem with this is that it will perform two lookups for 'john' instead of just one. If you're willing to use an extra line (and None is not a possible value you could get from the dictionary), you could do:

```
item = my_dict.get('john')
if item is None:
    item = default_value.copy()
```

EDIT: I thought I'd do some speed comparisons with timeit. The default_value and my_dict were globals. I did them each for both if the key was there, and if there was a miss.

Using exceptions:

```
def my_dict_get():
    try:
        item = my_dict['key']
    except KeyError:
        item = default_value.copy()

# key present: 0.4179
# key absent: 3.3799
```

Using get and checking if it's None.

```
def my_dict_get():
    item = my_dict.get('key')
    if item is None:
        item = default_value.copy()

# key present: 0.57189
# key absent: 0.96691
```

Checking its existance with the special if/else syntax

```
def my_dict_get():
    item = my_dict['key'] if 'key' in my_dict else default_value.copy()

# key present: 0.39721
# key absent: 0.43474
```

Naively copying the dictionary.

```
def my_dict_get():
    item = my_dict.get('key', default_value.copy())

# key present: 0.52303 (this may be lower than it should be as the dictionary I used was one element)
# key absent: 0.66045
```

For the most part, everything except the one using exceptions are very similar. The special if/else syntax seems to have the lowest time for some reason (no idea why).

Comment: This is a good point, I'll add a note to my answer. How about`'john' in my_dict` instead of `my_dict.has_key('john')` and `my_dict.get('john')` instead of `my_dict.get('john', None)`?

Comment: I like the use of in better than has_key. I forgot that existed. I didn't know that my_dict.get('john') defaulted to returning null (I thought it was an IndexError).

Comment: Or use this:
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(default_value.copy)

Then when you do mydict[key-thats-not-here], the function you passed to the constructor will be called.

Answer (score 10):

In Python dicts are both objects (so they are always passed as references) and mutable (meaning they can be changed without being recreated).

You can copy your dictionary each time you use it:

```
my_dict.get('john', default_value.copy())
```

You can also use the defaultdict collection:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def factory():
  return {'surname': '', 'age': 0}

my_dict = defaultdict(factory)

my_dict['john']
```

Answer (score 5):

The main thing to realize is that *everything* in Python is pass-by-reference. A variable name in a C-style language is usually shorthand for an object-shaped area of memory, and assigning to that variable makes a copy of another object-shaped area... in Python, variables are just keys in a dictionary (`locals()`), and the act of assignment just stores a new reference. (Technically, *everything* is a pointer, but that's an implementation detail).

This has a number of implications, the main one being there will never be an implicit copy of an object made because you passed it to a function, assigned it, etc. The only way to get a copy is to explicitly do so. The python stdlib offers a [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module which contains some things, including a `copy()` and `deepcopy()` function for when you want to explicitly make a copy of something. Also, some types expose a `.copy()` function of their own, but this is not a standard, or consistently implemented. Others which are immutable tend to sometimes offer a `.replace()` method, which makes a mutated copy.

---

In the case of your code, passing in the original instance obviously doesn't work, and making a copy ahead of time (when you may not need to) is wasteful. So the simplest solution is probably...

```
item = my_dict.get('john')
if item is None:
    item = default_dict.copy()
```

It would be useful in this case if `.get()` supported passing in a default value constructor function, but that's probably over-engineering a base class for a border case.

Answer (score 4):

because `my_dict.get('john', default_value.copy())` would create a copy of default dict **each time** get is called (even when 'john' is present and returned), it is faster and very OK to use this try/except option:

```
try:
    return my_dict['john']
except KeyError:
    return {'surname': '', 'age': 0}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections

def default_factory():
    return {'surname': '', 'age': 0}

my_dict = collections.defaultdict(default_factory)
```