# python dict: get vs setdefault

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

The following two expressions seem equivalent to me. Which one is preferable?

```
data = [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]

d1 = {}
d2 = {}

for key, val in data:
    # variant 1)
    d1[key] = d1.get(key, []) + [val]
    # variant 2)
    d2.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

The results are the same but which version is better or rather more pythonic?

Personally I find version 2 harder to understand, as to me setdefault is very tricky to grasp. If I understand correctly, it looks for the value of "key" in the dictionary, if not available, enters "[]" into the dict, returns a reference to either the value or "[]" and appends "val" to that reference. While certainly smooth it is not intuitive in the least (at least to me).

To my mind, version 1 is easier to understand (if available, get the value for "key", if not, get "[]", then join with a list made up from [val] and place the result in "key"). But while more intuitive to understand, I fear this version is less performant, with all this list creating. Another disadvantage is that "d1" occurs twice in the expression which is rather error-prone. Probably there is a better implementation using get, but presently it eludes me.

My guess is that version 2, although more difficult to grasp for the inexperienced, is faster and therefore preferable. Opinions?

Comment: "expressions seem equivalent to me"?  How so?  They do different things.  How can you ask which is preferred when they do different things?

Comment: Do they? Maybe the example I supplied is too minimalistic, but to me they seem to do the same thing. At least when I execute the code above, I get the same result for d1 and d2. Do you have a case at hand where the expressions do different things?

Comment: @Cerno, perhaps what S.Lott means is that the second modifies an existing list, while the first creates a new list by concatenation. The end result is the same in this case, but these two versions achieve it by different means. Under different circumstances, these two methods could produce very different effects. Specifically, version 2 could produce side-effects if there's another reference to the list somewhere.

Comment: @Cerno: These two example *statements* will have identical behavior.  The *expressions* however, which are part of those statements, are absolutely different, since one *expression* has a side-effect which the other *expression* does not have.  Are you asking about the *expressions* -- as stated in the question -- or are you asking about the *statements* (as a whole) -- as stated in the comment? Assignment is a *statement*.  `setdefault()` is an *expression*.  I find your question and comments confusing.  Can you please clarify which you are talking about?

Comment: @senderle: But that means that the question is still valid. You state that version 2 could produce side-effects, which do not occur in version 1. Assuming that I do not want to use any side effects that might occur, it should be possible to tell which of the versions is preferable in terms of stability. From your comment I gather it's version 1. But what about efficiency?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your two examples do the same thing, but that doesn't mean `get` and `setdefault` do.

The difference between the two is basically manually setting `d[key]` to point to the list every time, versus `setdefault` automatically setting `d[key]` to the list only when it's unset.

Making the two methods as similar as possible, I ran

```
from timeit import timeit

print timeit("c = d.get(0, []); c.extend([1]); d[0] = c", "d = {1: []}", number = 1000000)
print timeit("c = d.get(1, []); c.extend([1]); d[0] = c", "d = {1: []}", number = 1000000)
print timeit("d.setdefault(0, []).extend([1])", "d = {1: []}", number = 1000000)
print timeit("d.setdefault(1, []).extend([1])", "d = {1: []}", number = 1000000)
```

and got

```
0.794723378711
0.811882272256
0.724429205999
0.722129751973
```

So `setdefault` is around 10% faster than `get` for this purpose.

The `get` method allows you to do *less* than you can with `setdefault`. You can use it to avoid getting a `KeyError` when the key doesn't exist (if that's something that's going to happen frequently) even if you don't want to set the key.

See [Use cases for the 'setdefault' dict method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method) and [dict.get() method returns a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153893/dict-get-method-returns-a-pointer) for some more info about the two methods.

The thread about `setdefault` concludes that most of the time, you want to use a `defaultdict`. The thread about `get` concludes that it is slow, and often you're better off (speed wise) doing a double lookup, using a defaultdict, or handling the error (depending on the size of the dictionary and your use case).

Comment: Note that your `setdefault` version never actually stores the constructed list back in the dictionary, so you are comparing code that constructs a 10,000 element list by addition with code that constructs 10,000 1 element lists and throws them away. See my answer for more on this.

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer from agf isn't comparing like with like. After:

```
print timeit("d[0] = d.get(0, []) + [1]", "d = {1: []}", number = 10000)
```

`d[0]` contains a list with 10,000 items whereas after:

```
print timeit("d.setdefault(0, []) + [1]", "d = {1: []}", number = 10000)
```

`d[0]` is simply `[]`. i.e. the `d.setdefault` version never modifies the list stored in `d`. The code should actually be:

```
print timeit("d.setdefault(0, []).append(1)", "d = {1: []}", number = 10000)
```

and in fact is faster than the faulty `setdefault` example.

The difference here really is because of when you append using concatenation the whole list is copied every time (and once you have 10,000 elements that is beginning to become measurable. Using `append` the list updates are amortised O(1), i.e. effectively constant time.

Finally, there are two other options not considered in the original question: `defaultdict` or simply testing the dictionary to see whether it already contains the key.

So, assuming `d3, d4 = defaultdict(list), {}`

```
# variant 1 (0.39)
d1[key] = d1.get(key, []) + [val]
# variant 2 (0.003)
d2.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
# variant 3 (0.0017)
d3[key].append(val)
# variant 4 (0.002)
if key in d4:
    d4[key].append(val)
else:
    d4[key] = [val]
```

variant 1 is by far the slowest because it copies the list every time, variant 2 is the second slowest, variant 3 is the fastest but won't work if you need Python older than 2.5, and variant 4 is just slightly slower than variant 3.

I would say use variant 3 if you can, with variant 4 as an option for those occasional places where `defaultdict` isn't an exact fit. Avoid both of your original variants.

Comment: You're right, my examples were wrong, but luckily they didn't point in the wrong direction. I've fixed them a bit.

Answer (score 24):

For those who are still struggling in understanding these two term, let me tell you basic difference between get() and setdefault() method -

Scenario-1

```
root = {}
root.setdefault('A', [])
print(root)
```

Scenario-2

```
root = {}
root.get('A', [])
print(root)
```

In Scenario-1 output will be `{'A': []}` while in Scenario-2 `{}`

So `setdefault()` sets absent keys in the dict while `get()` only provides you default value but it does not modify the dictionary.

Now let come where this will be useful-
Suppose you are searching an element in a dict whose value is a list and you want to modify that list if found otherwise create a new key with that list.

using `setdefault()`

```
def fn1(dic, key, lst):
    dic.setdefault(key, []).extend(lst)
```

using `get()`

```
def fn2(dic, key, lst):
    dic[key] = dic.get(key, []) + (lst) #Explicit assigning happening here
```

Now lets examine timings -

```
dic = {}
%%timeit -n 10000 -r 4
fn1(dic, 'A', [1,2,3])
```

Took 288 ns

```
dic = {}
%%timeit -n 10000 -r 4
fn2(dic, 'A', [1,2,3])
```

Took 128 s

So there is a very large timing difference between these two approaches.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to look at `defaultdict` in the `collections` module.  The following is equivalent to your examples.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data:
    d[k].append(v)
```

There's more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I am aware of that, nevertheless I would like to know which of the original versions is preferable. Or would you say that using defaultdict is always the way to go? I try to avoid additional imports as best I can, therefore I normally go with the traditional dict. But probably that is a folly?

Comment: There are use cases for both `get` and `setdefault` that `defaultdict` doesn't cover.

Comment: "I try to avoid additional imports as best I can".  Please stop doing that.  It's a very bad policy and leads to needless complex programs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have some trouble deciding when it's fair to use an import because it's widely accepted and when to avoid it because it might lead to downward compatibility problems. Or should I stop worrying and assume everyone is using 2.7 and roll with it?

Comment: @Cerno, `defaultdict` has been around since 2.5 though -- not a lot of people are stuck at 2.4 these days. Overall I think this is the best answer -- `defaultdict` makes for readable code and it's implemented in c, so it's sure to be fast.

Comment: Thanks, that's some good advice! One question to agf though: You state that dict.get is fast but the time you measured for my example shows that using setdefault is a lot faster still. So I guess all in all defaultdict is the way to go in the end.

Comment: @Cerno Yeah that was a typo / brainfail. I meant `defaultdict` rather than `dict.get`. If it works for your use case, it'll be fastest.

Answer (score 10):

1. Explained with a good example here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66516-add-an-entry-to-a-dictionary-unless-the-entry-is-a/

> dict.**setdefault** typical usage
>   `somedict.setdefault(somekey,[]).append(somevalue)`
>
> dict.**get** typical usage
>   `theIndex[word] = 1 + theIndex.get(word,0)`

2. More explanation : http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

`dict.setdefault()` is equivalent to `get` or `set & get`. Or `set if necessary then get`. It's especially efficient if your dictionary key is expensive to compute or long to type.

The only problem with dict.setdefault() is that the default value is always evaluated, whether needed or not. That only **matters** if the default value is **expensive to compute**. In that case, use defaultdict.

3. Finally the official docs with difference highlighted  http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

> `get(key[, default])`
>   Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

> `setdefault(key[, default])`
>   If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, **insert key** with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of `dict.get` is:

```
if key in a_dict:
    value = a_dict[key] 
else: 
    value = default_value
```

Take an example:

```
In [72]: a_dict = {'mapping':['dict', 'OrderedDict'], 'array':['list', 'tuple']}
In [73]: a_dict.get('string', ['str', 'bytes'])
Out[73]: ['str', 'bytes']
In [74]: a_dict.get('array', ['str', 'byets'])
Out[74]: ['list', 'tuple']
```

The mechamism of `setdefault` is:

```
    levels = ['master', 'manager', 'salesman', 'accountant', 'assistant']
    #group them by the leading letter
    group_by_leading_letter = {}
    # the logic expressed by obvious if condition
    for level in levels:
        leading_letter = level[0]
        if leading_letter not in group_by_leading_letter:
            group_by_leading_letter[leading_letter] = [level]
        else:
            group_by_leading_letter[leading_letter].append(word)
    In [80]: group_by_leading_letter
    Out[80]: {'a': ['accountant', 'assistant'], 'm': ['master', 'manager'], 's': ['salesman']}
```

The setdefault dict method is for precisely this purpose. The preceding for loop can be rewritten as:

```
In [87]: for level in levels:
    ...:     leading = level[0]
    ...:     group_by_leading_letter.setdefault(leading,[]).append(level)
Out[80]: {'a': ['accountant', 'assistant'], 'm': ['master', 'manager'], 's': ['salesman']}
```

It's very simple, means that either a non-null list append an element or a null list append an element.

The `defaultdict`, which makes this even easier. To create one, you pass a type or function for generating the default value for each slot in the dict:

```
from collections import defualtdict
group_by_leading_letter = defaultdict(list)
for level in levels:
    group_by_leading_letter[level[0]].append(level)
```

Comment: This answer is misleading due to the drastically different presentation of each approach. There is functionally no difference between `get` and `setdefault` in the examples you provided, you just negated the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict answer to this question. They both accomplish the same purpose. They can both be used to deal with missing values on keys. The only difference that I have found is that with setdefault(), the key that you invoke (if not previously in the dictionary) gets automatically inserted while it does not happen with get(). Here is an example:
**Setdefault()**

```
>>> myDict = {'A': 'GOD', 'B':'Is', 'C':'GOOD'} #(1)
>>> myDict.setdefault('C')  #(2)
'GOOD'
>>> myDict.setdefault('C','GREAT')  #(3)
'GOOD'
>>> myDict.setdefault('D','AWESOME') #(4)
'AWESOME'
>>> myDict #(5)
{'A': 'GOD', 'B': 'Is', 'C': 'GOOD', 'D': 'AWSOME'} 
>>> myDict.setdefault('E')
>>>
```

**Get()**

```
>>> myDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}   #(1)
>>> myDict.get('a',0)   #(2)
1
>>> myDict.get('d',0)   #(3)
0
>>> myDict #(4)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Here is my conclusion: there is no specific answer to which one is best specifically when it comes to default values imputation. The only difference is that setdefault() automatically adds any new key with a default value in the dictionary while get() does not. For more information, please go [here](http://www.datasciencetopics.com/2020/04/python-dictionaries-part-2-advanced.html) !

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: person_dict = {}

In [2]: person_dict['liqi'] = 'LiQi'

In [3]: person_dict.setdefault('liqi', 'Liqi')
Out[3]: 'LiQi'

In [4]: person_dict.setdefault('Kim', 'kim')
Out[4]: 'kim'

In [5]: person_dict
Out[5]: {'Kim': 'kim', 'liqi': 'LiQi'}

In [8]: person_dict.get('Dim', '')
Out[8]: ''

In [5]: person_dict
Out[5]: {'Kim': 'kim', 'liqi': 'LiQi'}
```