# Python-dict setdefault - about using it only for setting

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

I see the discussion here [setdefault vs. get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22326645/5107386) and here [when using setdefault (vs. defaultdict)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483652/5107386).

My question is more about coding style.

It's agreed that we shouldn't use `setdefault` for simple dict setting:

```
d = {}
d[k] = v
```

but not:

```
d.setdefault(k, v)
```

(using `setdefault` hints that `k` might be already in `d` and we doesn't want to override it)

As mention in the links above - we also use `setdefault` when want to get reference to the `dict key`'s `value` (and use it)

```
d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Now, this is my case:

```
self._container["abc"] = self._object_handler.add(MyObject(*params))
instance = self._container["abc"]
instance.set_bla()
<more setting>
```

I need to do so several times so I would like to do all in one line.
Since I think it's not readable to assign twice in one line:

```
instance = self._container["abc"] = self._object_handler.add(MyObject(*params))
```

I think that using setdefault is better:

```
instance = self._container.setdefault("abc", self._object_handler.add(MyObject(*params)))
```

What do you say - is it also use case for `setdefault`?

Comment: It would not work if `self._container` already has `'abc'`  right?

Comment: right - but it's not my case - as I mention it's simple setting, and I only want to use `setdefault` for design considerations.