# Callable as the default argument to dict.get without it being called if the key exists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to provide a function as the default argument for the dictionary's get function, like this

```
def run():
   print "RUNNING"

test = {'store':1}
test.get('store', run())
```

However, when this is run, it displays the following output:

```
RUNNING
   1
```

so my question is, as the title says, is there a way to provide a callable as the default value for the get method without it being called if the key exists?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. You're asking about the default argument, but you're trying it on a key that does exist - obviously, `get` will return the value for that key if it exists. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanielRoseman His question is how does he get `run` to only be called if the value _doesn't_ exist, as for his current `get` it gets called no matter what. I clarified the last line of his question.

Comment: Why is `run()` called in the first place? One would think `get()` wouldn't bother with the default value unless it was needed.

Comment: @CalebKoch: `get` doesn't do anything with the second argument if it's not needed, but ignoring the argument doesn't stop it from being evaluated.

Comment: @CalebKoch You're suggesting that Python should not evaluate its function arugments before calling a function, but that instead the called function should evaluate them, in the caller's context, if and only if they're "needed".  That's not how argument passing works in Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the discussion in the answers and comments of [dict.get() method returns a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153893/dict-get-method-returns-a-pointer/7153919#7153919). You have to break it into two steps.

Your options are:

1. Use a `defaultdict` with the callable if you *always* want that value as the default, and want to store it in the `dict`.
2. Use a conditional expression:

   ```
   item = test['store'] if 'store' in test else run()
   ```
3. Use `try` / `except`:

   ```
   try:
       item = test['store']
   except KeyError:
       item = run()
   ```
4. Use `get`:

   ```
   item = test.get('store')
   if item is None:
       item = run()
   ```

And variations on those themes.

glglgl shows a way to subclass `defaultdict`, you can also just subclass `dict` for some situations:

```
def run():
    print "RUNNING"
    return 1

class dict_nokeyerror(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return run()

test = dict_nokeyerror()

print test['a']
# RUNNING
# 1
```

Subclassing only really makes sense if you *always* want the `dict` to have some nonstandard behavior; if you generally want it to behave like a normal `dict` and just want a lazy `get` in one place, use one of my methods 2-4.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a conditional, however i think using defaultdict does exactly what i need, im going to mark glglgl's answer as the accepted because he was first, but thanks a lot :P, rly appreciate it

Answer (score 19):

Another option, **assuming you don't intend to store falsy values** in your dictionary:

```
test.get('store') or run()
```

In python, the `or` operator does not evaluate arguments that are not needed (it short-circuits)

---

If you *do* need to support falsy values, then you can use `get_or_run(test, 'store', run)` where:

```py
def get_or_run(d, k, f):
    sentinel = object()  # guaranteed not to be in d
    v = d.get(k, sentinel)
    return f() if v is sentinel else v
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to have the callable applied only if the key does not exist.

There are several approaches to do so.
One would be to use a defaultdict, which calls `run()` if key is missing.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def run():
   print "RUNNING"

test = {'store':1}
test.get('store', run())

test = defaultdict(run, store=1) # provides a value for store
test['store'] # gets 1
test['runthatstuff'] # gets None
```

Another, rather ugly one, one would be to only save callables in the dict which return the apropriate value.

```
test = {'store': lambda:1}
test.get('store', run)() # -> 1
test.get('runrun', run)() # -> None, prints "RUNNING".
```

If you want to have the return value depend on the missing key, you have to subclass defaultdict:

```
class mydefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        val = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
        return val

d = mydefaultdict(lambda k: k*k)
d[10] # yields 100

@mydefaultdict # decorators are fine
def d2(key):
    return -key
d2[5] # yields -5
```

And if you want not to add this value to the dict for the next call, you have a

```
def __missing__(self, key): return self.default_factory(key)
```

instead which calls the default factory every time a `key: value` pair was not **explicitly** added.

Comment: Having to create `lambda`s around all of his data in the `dict` doesn't sound practical for the vast majority of real world situations. Unfortunately, the `defaultdict` also doesn't work for a lot of situations where you don't want to actually set values in the `dict` or you only want to get the default value in some situations.

Comment: It works if you subclass it - see my 3rd example after the edit.

Comment: That still stores the value in the `dict`, which he may or may not want to do.

Comment: right - it is just an example which can be modified to not store that value: `def __missing__(self, key): return self.default_factory(key)`. I wanted to keep it close to the original behaviour. -> another edit

Comment: If you're not storing in the `dict` just use a regular `dict` subclass with `__missing__` overridden, not a `defaultdict`.

Comment: `defaultdict` gives me a handy `default_factory()` which I otherwise have to plug in manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```py
def lazy_get(d, k, f):
  return d[k] if k in d else f(k)
```

The fallback function `f` takes the key as an argument, e.g.

```py
lazy_get({'a': 13}, 'a', lambda k: k)  # --> 13
lazy_get({'a': 13}, 'b', lambda k: k)  # --> 'b'
```

You would obviously use a more meaningful fallback function, but this illustrates the flexibility of `lazy_get`.

---

Here's what the function looks like with type annotation:

```py
from typing import Callable, Mapping, TypeVar

K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')

def lazy_get(d: Mapping[K, V], k: K, f: Callable[[K], V]) -> V:
  return d[k] if k in d else f(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only know what the callable is likely to be at he get call site you could subclass dict something like this

```
    class MyDict(dict):

        def get_callable(self,key,func,*args,**kwargs):
            '''Like ordinary get but uses a callable to 
            generate the default value'''

            if key not in self:
                val = func(*args,**kwargs)
            else:
                val = self[key]
            return val
```

This can then be used like so:-

```
     >>> d = MyDict()
     >>> d.get_callable(1,complex,2,3)
     (2+3j)
     >>> d[1] = 2
     >>> d.get_callable(1,complex,2,3)
     2
     >>> def run(): print "run"
     >>> repr(d.get_callable(1,run))
     '2'
     >>> repr(d.get_callable(2,run))
     run
     'None'
```

This is probably most useful when the callable is expensive to compute.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `util` directory in my project with `qt.py`, `general.py`, `geom.py`, etc.  In `general.py` I have a bunch of python tools like the one you need:

```
# Use whenever you need a lambda default
def dictGet(dict_, key, default):
    if key not in dict_:
        return default()
    return dict_[key]
```

Add `*args, **kwargs` if you want to support calling default more than once with differing args:

```
def dictGet(dict_, key, default, *args, **kwargs):
    if key not in dict_:
        return default(*args, **kwargs)
    return dict_[key]
```